# Spring Boot @Autowired после пустого конструктора

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

Добрый день.

Подскажите каким образом можно выполнить DI если необходимо что бы в классе был пустой конструктор? 
ЗЫ: при использовании Spring Boot, а не Spring. На сколько я понял в Spring Boot можно автосвязывание вешать только на конструктор.

Пример проблемы:

Класс ниже работает корректно, но в моем случае не подходит т.к. необходимо что бы был конструктор без параметров (в противном случае ошибка)

```
@Component
public class ContactMapStoreImpl implements ContactMapStore {

    private ContactRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ContactMapStoreImpl(ContactRepository repository){
         this.repository = repository
    }

     public List<Contact> findAll() {
        return this.repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

При попытке выполнить вот такой вариант (или повесить DI на геттер\сеттер) - внедрение зависимости не происходит и при вызове метода findAll() -ошибка: repository NullPoinerExcetion

```
@Component
public class ContactMapStoreImpl implements ContactMapStore {

    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository repository;


    public ContactMapStoreImpl(){}

     public List<Contact> findAll() {
        return this.repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Примечание: внутри repository спрятан JdbcTemplate, который тоже очень удобно инжектиться сами спрингом. По этом сделать каокй, нибудь @PostConstructor и в нем выполнить  repository = new ContacrtRepositoryImpl(new JdbcTemplate()) не поллучиться и собственно хардкодить и создавать отдельный класс специально для такого случая не хочеться. У Spring подобных проблем нет, думаю и у Spring Boot должно быть какое-то удобное решение.

Comment: Весь фокус - в том, кто именно вызывает конструктор. Если конструктор вызывается самим Spring - то *не может быть требования о пустом списке параметров!* А если конструктор вызывается кем-то еще - то никакие @Autowired работать не будут.

Comment: Таким образом, требования *"выполнить DI"* и *"необходимо что бы в классе был пустой конструктор"* противоречат друг другу.

Comment: Вам надо разбираться не с танцами вокруг @Autowired - а искать какого фига требуется пустой конструктор.

Answer (score -2):

Всем спасибо за советы.
Решение проблемы найдено.

Действительно класс в котором требовался пустой конструктор был не управляемый спрингом. Вот здесь и было найдено решение:
Создать класс, который бы управлялся спрингом и в него внедрить требуемый мне объект, а потом из дефолтного конструктора вызвать этот метод.

```
@Component
public class DataManager {
    private static ContactRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public DataManager(ContactRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public static ContactRepository getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }
}
```

А вот как выглядит мой класс теперь

```
public class ContactMapStoreImpl implements ContactMapStore {
    private ContactRepository repository;

    public ContactMapStoreImpl(){
          repository = DataManager.getRepository();
    }

     public List<Contact> findAll() {
        return this.repository.findAll();
    }
}
```